# Фантомная граница table в DIV

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, firefox, кроссбраузерность

Здравствуйте!
Возникла такая проблема. Потребовалось сверстать для клиентской части веб-приложения таблицу с динамическим прокручиваемым содержимым. Я реализовал это методом вложения div с динамической таблицей внутрь статической.  По мере тестирования в разных браузерах обнаружил, что Firefox дорисовывает невидимую границу для вложенной таблицы слева и сверху. В результате этого таблица смещается соответственно вниз и вправо на один пиксель и вид портится. Все остальные браузеры в этом месте срабатывают, как задумано, ибо все границы элементов, охватывающих внутреннюю таблицу, заданы как `border:none`.

Ниже скриншоты поведения браузеров Chrome и Firefox. IE выкладывать не стал, ибо он, как и хром в этом случае работает корректно.

**Отображение (Chrome vs Firefox):**

**Chrome**
[image: Chrome]

**Firefox**
[image: Firefox]

**Интерпретация стилей (Chrome vs Firefox):**

**Chrome**
[image: Ok]

**Firefox**
[image: Bug]

На лицо явный баг со стороны Firefox. Но обойти эту неприятность не удается никак. Увы, но `border-collapse: separate` для внутренней таблицы тоже ситуацию не спасает.

Подскажите как быть? Очень нужно исправить эту проблему. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Зачем таблицу класть в таблицу в вашем случае? На последнем скриншоте вижу 3 оберточных дива от плагина скролла, о которых вы ничего не сказали. Пример кода?

Comment: @mJeevas Да забыл упонямнуть о плагине для кастомизации полосы прокрутки. Код нужен исходный или тот, что в итоге генерируется (DOM) и отображается в инспекторе элементов браузера?